# Convergence test for $\Sigma \frac{1}{n^\alpha}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

[image]

This is a convergence test in my textbook for $\Sigma \frac{1}{n^\alpha}$. What I don't understand is why is it that the sum is less than the integral for $\alpha>1$ but the sum is bigger than the integral for $\alpha\leq 1$?

Comment: The sum starts at 2 in the first case and 1 in the second. (Why can we do this?)

Comment: Note the two sums start at different values of $n$.

Comment: @Ben, so if the second sum starts from $2$, then sum will be less than the integral to? i.e. in general if the sum starts from $1$ then the sum is bigger than the integral?

Comment: yes - there's a pretty standard image of this if you search 'harmonic series integral test' - which 'proves' it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if $f$ is a continuous decreasing function from $[1,\infty)$ into $[0,\infty)$, then$$f(n+1)\leqslant\int_n^{n+1}f(x)\,\mathrm dx\leqslant f(n)$$and therefore$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty f(n)\leqslant\int_1^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx\leqslant\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n).$$This is the basic ingredient in one of the proofs of the integral test.