# Prove and determine all values of p for which the sequence below converges, in light of the conditions given.

Tags: real-analysis

How do I prove the following:
Let p > 0 be a real number and let (a_n) be a sequence of positive real numbers s.t. lim as n approaches infinity n^p(a_n) ^1/2 = 1. Prove and determine all values of p for which ∑_n (from 1 to infinity) a_n converges. [image]

Comment: What about the limit of $n^{2p}a_n.$.

Answer (score -1):

First we know that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{a_n} = \sqrt{\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n}$$
And so we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{2p} a_n = \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} n^p a_n^\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = 1^2 = 1$$

Now we consider the sequence $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ given by $b_n = \frac{1}{n^{2p}}$ Then $\frac{1}{b_n} = n^{2p}$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} n^{2p} a_n = 1$$

We know by the limit comparison theorem that, for two sequences $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}, (b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ exists and is not $0$ then either both $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ converge or both diverge. Therefore $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ converges.

We also know that the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^\alpha}$$
converges iff $\alpha > 1$.

And so the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ will converge if and only if
\begin{align}
2p &> 1 \\
\Rightarrow p &> \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

Comment: How do you go from the first to the second step in your answer?

Comment: @FedericoGuerrera could you clarify which "step" you mean exactly. What part is confusing you?

Comment: The only step that remains unclear is the following statement:                             We also know that the series
∑n( from 1 to ∞)= 1/n^α
converges iff α>1.   Could you explain this step in more details?                                 I was also wondering is there only one value of p for which the series converges?

Comment: @FedericoGuerrera It's a result that can be proven. I'm sure there is a proof of it online somewhere. Have a look online to try and find it. If you can't find it anywhere I can edit my post with a proof. For the second part, as in my answer I believe the series converges for all $p > \frac{1}{2}$, so I don't think there is only one value of p. I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: I  think this result is proven here: @MISC {4337065,
    TITLE = {Convergence test for $\Sigma \frac{1}{n^\alpha}$},
    AUTHOR = {user3741635 (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/306026/user3741635)},
    HOWPUBLISHED = {Mathematics Stack Exchange},
    NOTE = {URL:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4337065 (version: 2021-12-18)},
    EPRINT = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4337065},
    URL = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4337065}
}

Comment: My last question: how do you go from "we know that the series ∑n( from 1 to ∞)= 1/n^α converges iff α>1" to "And so the series ∑n (from 1 to ∞) b_n will converge …"? What are the steps that lead you to argue that?

Comment: @FedericoGuerrera By the limit comparison theorem we have that either both $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge or neither converge. So for our original series of $a_n$ to converge we need $b_n$ to converge, which is what we use the arguement of the $1/n^\alpha$ to show.

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you so very much for your kind and precious contribution.